# Organizing large numbers of vector layers with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers

I have a large number (100,000+) of vehicle GPS paths in a PostGIS database. I need access to all of them on my web page, however, I don't usually need to view more than a handful on the map at any one time.

Should I be making all of these paths into layers, or is there a better way to go about it? (Possible example: I'd love it if my JS client could request data for certain location and time frames, and GeoServer could dynamically make layers from the database data, serve those layers, and maybe get rid of them when finished.)

If I am making each path into a layer, is there a way to organize that many layers on the GeoServer admin page, rather than just a gigantic list?

Additionally, is there a way to organize how these layers are sent to my web page? The most helpful way would be to only receive the names of layers that could be viewable currently on the map, but I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: On the server side, I would go with 1 layer that can be filtered, like in Geoserver layer preview. It contains all the data and you request 1 or more record from it. On the client side, you can either have all the filtered data in 1 OL layer or in several ones (to turn them on/off), but they all point to the same geoserver layer